# Print another view from present view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to print different controller/view from present view. There are 2 controllers namely ProductsController and AddressController and views to display Products and Address. From Products view, how to print Address view?

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetProdcuts()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

public class AddressController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetAddress()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

---

GetProducts.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function print() {

            var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
            var printContent =@Url.Action("GetAddress", "Address");
            document.body.innerHTML = printContent;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
        }

    </script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GetProdcuts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <h1>Products Page</h1>


        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print();">Print products</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="print()">Print address</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

GetAddress.cshml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GetAddress</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 

        <h1>Address page</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"Print products" works as expected. But "Print Address" throws error.

Answer (score 0):

you can create separate view model in which you can add both product and address details and call it in view like:

@model projectname.ProductAddressViewModel

and access the elements in that view model

Comment: Rather than creating viewmodel, will it be possible to directly call GetAddress action from Product view and print Address view?